# How to add a hard code of subs to this filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:11:47.970 -t 3.090 -i "file.mkv" -ss 00:11:46.470 -t 1.500 -i "file" -ss 00:11:51.060 -t 0.960 -i "file.mkv" -an -c:v libvpx -crf 31 -b:v 10000k -y -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa];[outv]scale='min(960,iw)':-1[outv];[outv]subtitles='file.srt'[outv]" -map [outv] file_out.webm -map [outa] file.mp3
```

I have a filter where take three different points in a file concat them together and scale them down this part works

Im looking to see how to add to the filter_complex a sub burn in step rendering the subs from the exact timings usings a file that I specify when I use the above code it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The subtitles filter is receiving a concatenated stream. It does not contain the timestamps from the original segments. So the subtitles filter starts from the beginning. I'm assuming this is the problem when you said, "it doesn't work".

The simple method to solve this is to make temporary files then concatenate them.

1. Output segments

   ```
   ffmpeg -ss 00:11:47.970 -t 3.090 -copyts -i "file.mkv" -filter_complex "scale='min(960,iw)':-1,subtitles='file.srt',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS;asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -crf 31 -b:v 10000k temp1.webm
   ffmpeg -ss 00:11:46.470 -t 1.500 -copyts -i "file.mkv" -filter_complex "scale='min(960,iw)':-1,subtitles='file.srt',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS;asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -crf 31 -b:v 10000k temp2.webm
   ffmpeg -ss 00:11:51.060 -t 0.960 -copyts -i "file.mkv" -filter_complex "scale='min(960,iw)':-1,subtitles='file.srt',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS;asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -crf 31 -b:v 10000k temp3.webm
   ```

   The timestamps are reset when fast seek is used (`-ss` before `-i`). `-copyts`will preserve the timestamps so the subtitles filter knows where to start the subtitles.
2. Make `input.txt`:

   ```
   file 'temp1.webm'
   file 'temp2.webm'
   file 'temp3.webm'
   ```
3. Concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.webm
   ```

   `-c copy` enables [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode so it avoids re-encoding to concatenate.